# NullPointerException in a for-loop in UVa Crypt Kicker II

Tags: java

I was trying to solve this problem in UVa, but I get a NullPointerException at line 16 (at the for loop). I'm fairly new in Java and I don't know why is it happening. The output looks okay, but I would like to know why it is returning a NPE. Here's my code:

```
import java.io.*;

class Crypt {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    String line = "";
    String buffer = "";
    char[][] hash = {{'a', 'p'}, {'b', 'l'}, {'c', 'o'}, {'d', 'k'}, {'e', 'm'},
             {'f', 'i'}, {'g', 'j'}, {'h', 'n'}, {'i', 'u'}, {'j', 'h'},
             {'k', 'b'}, {'l', 'y'}, {'m', 'g'}, {'n', 'v'}, {'o', 't'},
             {'p', 'f'}, {'q', 'c'}, {'r', 'r'}, {'s', 'd'}, {'t', 'x'}, 
             {'u', 'e'}, {'v', 's'}, {'w', 'z'}, {'x', 'a'}, {'y', 'q'},
             {'z', 'w'}};

    BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("crypt.in"));
    while(f != null) {
        line = f.readLine();
        buffer = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if(line.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            buffer += ' ';
        } else {
            for(int j = 0; j < hash.length; j++) {
            if(line.charAt(i) == hash[j][1]) {
                buffer += hash[j][0];
            }
            }
        }
        } 
        System.out.println(buffer);
    } 
    }
}
```

I'm looking forward for a good explanation. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `line` variable seems to be `null`. Use `f.ready()` to check if there are any more lines remaining in the file. `f != null` is incorrect because it merely tests if the `BufferedReader` object `f` exists, so it will never be false in this case.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Java Docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html#readLine%28%29) the `readline()` method of a `BufferedReader` returns `null` when the end of the input steam is reached and else the line just read.
Therefore the NullPointerException is always thrown on the last line of a file. You could easily go around this by changing your while condition to:

```
while (line = f.readline() != null) {
```

which would assign the new line to the variable `line` and only proceed if it isn't `null`.

edit:

As someone mentioned you should check if the file you're reading really exists. The simples way to do this is by catching the `FileNotFoundException` thrown by the `FileReader` if a file does not exist or is a directory or for some other reason cannot be opened for reading. For more info see the Java Docs on [FileReader](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/io/FileReader.html#FileReader%28java.io.File%29).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in your while loop.
The BufferedReader will never be null. You initialize right above the loop.

So `while(f!=null)`  is equivalent to `while(true)`

The readLine() function returns a null string, which throws an error when you call `line.length()`

Here's my quick solution:

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("crypt.in"));
 while(true) {
     line = f.readLine();
     if(line == null)
          break;
     buffer = "";
     ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code

```
BufferedReader f = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("crypt.in"));
    while((line = f.readLine()) != null) {
        buffer = "";
        for(int i = 0; i < line.length(); i++) {
        if(line.charAt(i) == ' ') {
            buffer += ' ';
        } else {
            for(int j = 0; j < hash.length; j++) {
            if(line.charAt(i) == hash[j][1]) {
                buffer += hash[j][0];
            }
            }
        }
```